# How to import from the database a list of companies in the live search?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

```
import css from './SearchField.styl';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import CN from 'classnames';
import CompanyList from 'Company/List/CompanyList';
import Autosuggest from 'react-autosuggest';

const suburbs = ['Cheltenham', 'Mill Park', 'Mordialloc', 'Nunawading'];


export default class SearchInput extends Component {

  render() {

    function getSuggestions(input, callback) {
      const regex = new RegExp('^' + input, 'i');
      const suggestions = suburbs.filter(suburb => regex.test(suburb));

      setTimeout(() => callback(null, suggestions), 300); // Emulate API call
    }
    return (
      <div className={CN(css.selectLive)}>
        <Autosuggest suggestions={getSuggestions} />
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

I have a list of companies , a component 
How do I connect to the live search ? I am new and it is impossible to connect the data from the database

Comment: Would you actually like the javascript (getSuggestions) method to retrieve the data from the database? In most cases you would make a call (async) to a web service to retrieve the possible suggestions.